# Filter on second level in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a table workstation and comments. When I asked for the list of workstations I want to inclued only the lastest comment for the workstation. Due to reduction of data and performance. But I can't figure out how to write into one query. What exactly should I do?

```
var workstations = this.context.TWorkstation.Include(x => x.TComments).AsQueryable();
workstations = workstations.SelectMany(x => x.TComments.Max(y => y.CreationDate)).ToList();
```

Currently the repsonse looks like this and contains id 1 and id2 of the comments. But it should only contain id 2

```
"workstation": "workstaionName",
"alias": "alias",
"dns": "ip",
"macAddress": "FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-F",
"comments": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "text": "test\n",
        "creationDate": "2020-11-16T17:41:40.226617",
        "modificationDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "creator": "xxx"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "text": "test2",
        "creationDate": "2020-11-17T17:41:40.226617",
        "modificationDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "creator": "xxx"
    }
],
"creator": "xxx"
```

Comment: workstations.SelectMany(x => x.Select(y => new {param1 = y.param1, param2 = y.param2})).ToList();

Comment: Sorry tried my best to adapt your answer but could not get it to work. I've edit the question to hopefully better explain what I am trying to archive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In EF Core 5, you can do the following:

```cs
var workstations = this.context.TWorkstation
   .Include(x => x.TComments.OrderByDescending(c => c.CreationDate).Take(1))
   .ToList();
```